# Ros Dynamic Config file

Tags: c++, config, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, ros

I am trying to perform a segmentation task with PCL/ROS. I am using the dynamic configuration option in ROS as the number of inputs to my segmentation task is large and would like to study the influence of each `param`. There is no problem with my C++ source code, however when I try to run the launch file my file publisher is not able to find the PCD files.

```
<launch>

<!-- Start segmentation analysis -->
<node pkg="segmentation_analysis" name="region_growing" type="region_growing" output="screen">
    <remap from="selected_file" to="/selected_file" />
</node>

    <node pkg="file_selection" name="file_publisher" type="file_publisher" args="/home/anirudh/getbot/ros/3d_scene_analysis/segmentation_analysis">
            <param name="extension" value="pcd"/>
            <remap from="~file" to="/selected_file"/>
    </node>


    <node pkg="rqt_reconfigure" name="rqt_reconfigure" type="rqt_reconfigure" >
    </node>
```

But when I run the launch file, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [file_selection/file_publisher]: can't locate node [file_publisher] in package [file_selection]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For ROS related questions there is http://answers.ros.org

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your error is not related to not finding PCD files.

It says

```
can't locate node [file_publisher] in package [file_selection]
```

So it cannot find the program **file_publisher**.

So check that:

1. The package **file_selection** exists.
2. The executable file **file_publisher** exists inside that package.

To check the first item:

If you type:

```
roscd file_selection
```

...does the current working directory switch to the **file_selection** package?
If that doesn't work, figure out why. If it does, try the next step:

To check the second item:

```
roscd file_selection
find . -executable
```

...and check if the output contains **file_publisher**.

Go from there.

**Edit**: Also note that for ROS related questions there is [answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org)