# PTAM CameraCalibrator error

Tags: camera-calibration, ros

I am trying to run the cameracalibrator.launch using ptam according to http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam/Tutorials/camera_calibration. However, when I do so, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ptam/cameracalibrator]: can't locate node [cameracalibrator] in package [ptam]
```

I source my devel/setup.bash before I run the code as well and it still does not work. Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node name="cameracalibrator" pkg="ptam" type="cameracalibrator" clear_params="true" output="screen">
        <remap from="image_raw" to usb_cam/image_raw" />
        <remap from="pose" to="pose"/>
        <rosparam file="$(find ptam)/PtamFixParams.yaml"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

Here is what I get for `rostopic list`:

```
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/svo/dense_input
/svo/image
/svo/image/compressed
/svo/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
...
/tf
/usb_cam/camera_info
/usb_cam/image_raw
/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed
...
/usb_cam/image_raw/theora
/usb_cam/image_raw/parameter_descriptions
/usb_cam/image_raw/parameter_updates
```

The path where the cameracalibration.launch file is `catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_ptam/ptam/launch`.

I am not sure why this error keeps coming up because when I run `roslaunch ptam cameracalibrator.launch`, it says:

```
NODES
  /
    cameracalibrator (ptam/cameracalibrator)
```

So I'm thinking that ptam does include cameracalibrator. If someone could please point out my error, that would be really helpful. I've been using this post as a guide, but it's not been helping me much: [Ros Dynamic Config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759356/ros-dynamic-config-file)

As it says in the above link, I tried `find . -executable` and I could not find cameracalibrator. I could only find the below. How do I proceed?

```
./include
./include/ptam
./cfg
...
./launch
./src
./src/ptam
./src/ptam/cfg
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: The executables are not stored in the source directory but in `devel`. In your case, if everything compiled correctly, it should be located in `catkin_ws/devel/lib/ptam`. Is it present there?

Comment: There is no ptam file in lib unfortunately. Here is what I get when I `ls` into `catkin_ws/devel/lib`: `libsvo.so libsvo_visualizer.so libusb_cam.so libvikit_common.so libvikit_ros.so pkgconfig python2.7 svo svo_ros usb_cam vikit_common`

Comment: Seems like the node is not build correctly. Is it listed somewhere in the output of `catkin_make`? There should be a line like "Build target cameracalibrator".

Comment: Yeah, wasn't able to find it. I actually decided to just manually make the file based off a different calibration format, so got the problem solved. Thanks though luator!